# How to compare inserted value with stored value

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

Query:

User input value(varchar) through sponsor id page (Simple form), then if id matched then move to registration page, for registration.

Verify Page:

```
<form action="verify_check.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">

    <label>
        <span>Sponser ID :</span>
        <input type="text" name="token" value="" />
    </label>

     <label>
        <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="SignUp"  name="submit"/> 
    </label>    
</form>
```

Verify_check Page:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$token=$_POST['token'];
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "gold_99") ;

if(!$conn)
{
die("connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM personal_deatils WHERE userid = '$token'";
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)
 if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
 {
    if($row =="$token"){
    echo "Data Select Succefully";
    }
    else
    echo "Wrong Connection";

} 

else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Database Architecture:

title (varchar), firstname (varchar), userid (varchar, primary), mobileno (varchar), email (varchar), country (varchar)

Comment: Do you at least know how to connect to DB from PHP and execute a query?

Comment: what kind of database?

Comment: @Smriti-Techno-Logics What? `header("Location:/mlm project/signup.php.");` No sir, you don't. I am sorry, but you better to learn some basics first.

Comment: on signup page its redirect to submit and on that page it connects to database

Comment: And boil down your example code to be relevant for the question, nobody needs a list of all countries and stuff.

Comment: @Smriti-Techno-Logics: This will be a good start for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mysql+basic+tutorial

Answer (score 0):

To use this solution, you have to store the generated token in database, 
say in user table or if you want you can save it in different table with respective to user id. For now, let's consider that whatever code you have stored in the session is stored in the user table too.

As you are asking a user to enter a verification code in the text box and you are sending the form to `verify_check.php`. Now at `verify_check` file you can get whatever code was entered by the user.

Now you can verify if the user's ***entered value*** is equal to ***sessions value*** as you have already done.

```
if (isset($_POST['token']) && isset($_SESSION['token']) && ($_POST['token']  == $_SESSION['token'])) {
```

Now you can query your database against this token and check whether you are getting any record for that user.

```
$con = mysql_connect("your_Hostname","your_username","your_password");

if (!$con) {
    die("Not able to connect the database")
}

$db = mysql_select_db("your_databasename",$con);
if (!$db) {
    die("Database not found");
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `your_table_name` 
        WHERE  `token` = '" .$_POST['token']. "'";

$res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($res) {
   $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
      if (isset($result['column_name_from_table_in_which_you_have_saved_user_id_at_registration_time'])) {
         @header("Location:/mlm project/signup.php.");
      }
} else {
     echo "Error, Wrong Sponser ID " ;
  } 
}
```

Comment: SQL INJECTION DANGER ZONE

Comment: Verify_check.php                                  <?php 
session_start();

error_reporting(0);
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") ;
$db=mysql_select_db("gold_99",$con) ; 

if(isset($_POST['token']) && isset($_SESSION['token']) && ($_POST['token'] == $_SESSION['token']))

$sql = "SELECT * FROM personal_deatils WHERE token = '" .$_POST['token']. "'";

  $res = mysql_query($sql);
  if ($res) {
      $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
      if (isset($result['userid'])) {
         @header("Location:/mlm project/signup.php.");
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error, Wrong Sponser ID " ;
  } 
?>

Comment: verify.php code--><?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['token'] = "";

?><form action="verify_check.php" method="post" class="basic-grey">
      
    <label>
     <span>Sponser ID :</span>
        <input type="text" name="token" value="" />
    </label>
    
     <label>
     <span>&nbsp;</span> 
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="SignUp"  name="submit"/> 
    </label>

Comment: Data Base Table name: personal_deatils, Structure--> title, firstname, userid, mobileno, email, country...all are varchar, except mobileno. Plz help ...i am in big trouble...

Comment: @SmritiTechnoLogics: Ok first thing is that you have made a mistake in table strucutre. The token column is missing in your table which we are using in WHERE clause. Additionaly you have to set a primary key for your table named as userid in your case with type integer and it should be auto increment.

Comment: @AlankarMore I updated query, please have a look and please suggest best.

Comment: Please send your updated table struture.As you are executing query in database against the value of token then there should be a record in table with that token number for some user. means as per your table structure  title, firstname, userid, mobileno, email, country,token. There should be a record in table with following values. testtitle, testuserfirstname, 1, 9999456213, testuseremail@some.com, India,testtokennumber123434. If it is not there this means you don't have any user with this testtokennumber123434.